# Ask SQL Server to run a query but return results when i ask for results

Tags: sql-server, database-design, query

I don't know if SQL Server can do this or not. It is just my idea of how i want SQL server to behave.

I want to send a Query to SQL Server but do not want results returned back immediately. Instead i want a Ticket number (a process # or transaction # whatever). But SQL server execute the query immediately and keep the results in memory(a table , cache or something where rows are kept for later use).

Later when I need results I issue another request to the SQL Server and pass the Ticket Number with the request so that SQL server can identify what data i am looking for.

Server then send me the location of my data against which i can issue fetch request by range of rows. I may ask server to send me rows from 10 to 100 for example.

There are a number of advantages i am looking for in this behavior. Please focus on above points instead of asking me what advantages. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This process has multiple advantages. 1- I can go for results when i need them. 2- Snapshot of records on specific time period 3- No network failure issue. 4- On client side multiple DataWindows can be assigned to attach results at runtime depending on timer event. 5- perfectly fit for dashboard when any long running queries gonna take time. 6- Multi threading kind of setup handled on client side. Whole bunch of advantages are there but people tend to hit negative when things go swinging over their heads.

Comment: I have no code at all. and even if i provide the code there gonna be many chunks linked together and gonna be quite difficult to summarize things here. I asked just for idea if it is possible? and if possible then what is the idea behind it?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like Sql Server Reporting Services (SSRS). It can run the query ahead of time; cache the results for the users to retrieve later.